# 403 access forbidden error - spring security when the url has dynamic path param

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I have a resource called USER for my rest service.
Follwing are some apis from this resource.

/api/users/{userId}/order/{orderId} 
  /api/users/{userId}/favoriteStores

I want the first URL to be protected while the second one need no security.(giving an example api urls).

I configured the security config as follows

```
  <security:http pattern="/rest/users/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
            position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/{userId}/order/**"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER')" />
        <security:logout />
    </security:http>
```

But this intercepts the second url also(Which is /api/users/{userId}/favoriteStores)

So , I changed the config to

```
<security:http pattern="/rest/users/{userId}/order/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
            <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
                position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/{userId}/order/**"
                access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER')" />
            <security:logout />
        </security:http>
```

Now it shows forbidden error.

How should i configure the securit intercept urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring security, if you doesn't want to intercept the URL pattern then you must provide the access value as permitAll. Also URL pattern must match exactly as you want to. Like from your example if you want to permit the url pattern `rest/users/{userId}/favoriteStores` then u must add a intercept pattern like this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/*/favoriteStores/**"
                access="permitAll" />
```

For more information you can go through spring link [for spring Expression-Based Access Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Comment: @user5118993 You should accept the answer if it works.

Comment: @DavidA I don't have enough reputations yet to upvote the answer

Comment: You don't have to upvote it, just click on the 'check' under the votes to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Ah ok. got it. Done ! @DavidA

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to intercept the url at all you can simply do

```
<http pattern="/rest/users/*/favoriteStores/**" security="none"/>
```

Comment: I used security="none" but it threw an error saying cannot resolve this tag. I am using spring 4 and spring-security 4